# heartBeatIntervalInSecs does not have effect if the application starts with the server stopped

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

WL 6.1

I have an application with:

```
ConnectOnStartup: true
heartBeatIntervalInSecs: 30
```

If the server is started and I start the application I can see in the application log a trace each 30sec for the heartbeat

But if the server is stopped and I start the application there is no trace for the heartbeat.

I handle the connection error with the onConnectionFailure and I let the application to start.

Is this ok? How could I enable the heartbeat manually?

I have tested this on Android.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is API for this: `WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval(interval)`
Accepts:

- -1 to disable
- Any other number (in seconds)

In your implementation simply either disable or enable (by setting an interval) whenever required.

Comment: Thank you Idan, I do not have the device now but as soon as I get it I will test the API.